# Hibernate NamedQuery using Oracle rownum and order by

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA Hibernate implementation and I'm trying to create a namedquery that is ordered by a data and then just grab the first two rows.  I've tried the below, but it ins't valid.  Any ideas? I'm using Oracle DBMS.

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "Test.getLastTwoRecords", 
        query = "SELECT a FROM Test a WHERE rownum < 3 in (SELECT b FROM Test b WHERE b.value = :value order by b.date desc)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Test.getOrderedRecords", query = "SELECT a FROM Test a WHERE a.value = :value order by a.date desc)")
```

and then:

```
List results = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Test.getOrderedRecords").setParameter("value", X).setMaxResults(2).getResultList();
```

JPA is usually clever enough to figure out the best possible approach to truncate list of results.